# ggplot2 rendering problems with gWidgets

Tags: r, ggplot2, gwidgets

There seems to be something odd going on with ggplot2 & gWidgets. See an example and the resulting image below.

Is there a way to make the facet labels render properly in gWidgets?

```
library(gWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

win <- gwindow("Graphics example")
ggraphics(cont = win)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Might need some more information. I can't replicate this behavior with gWidgetsRGtk2 or gWidgetsQt under OS X. Feel free to email offline. --John

Comment: I see the same thing as shown in the question (malformed facet labels): `R version 2.15.0`, `x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`; `cairoDevice_2.19`, `gWidgetsRGtk2_0.0-81`, `ggplot2_0.9.1`, `gWidgets_0.0-50`. @learnr: include your `sessionInfo()` please.

Comment: R version 2.14.1, i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
other attached packages:
[1] cairoDevice_2.19     gWidgetsRGtk2_0.0-81 ggplot2_0.9.1       
[4] gWidgets_0.0-50     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       grid_2.14.1       
 [5] labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-16        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3       
 [9] plyr_1.7.1         proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1    
[13] RGtk2_2.20.24      scales_0.2.1       stringr_0.6

Comment: @learnr You should add that to the question instead of having it as a comment.